# Specifying Javascript in a header template for a column on my Kendo MVC grid just renders the Javascript (Kendo UI MVC)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When specifying Javascript in a header template for a column on my grid, the result renders the javascript itself and does not evoke the method and render the result of the method.

Specifying the exact same code in the ClientHeader does work.  Are we not able to process Javascript in HeaderTemplates?

Or is there a different syntax / mechanism?

Note, I'm trying to do this in ASP.NET MVC Kendo, not the JQuery Kendo (and I am a Kendo novice)

```
    c.Bound(b => b)
        .Title("Dates")
        .Filterable(false)
        .Sortable(false)
        .HeaderTemplate("<span> #= new Date().getFullYear() #</span>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC Grid header templates are server templates. Currently you are trying to use a client-side Kendo UI template, which works in databound rows.

Consider using a server-side expression that will return the desired year as a string and it will be rendered as expected. No `#= ... #` expressions will be necessary.

Comment: That works, it would be nice to be able to hook into client side but that does enable to remove some hardcoded values.  Thanks